# webscraping using request Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, timer, web-scraping, httprequest

I used my request like this `htmltext = requests.get(urls[0]).content` but sometime it takes too long to get the urls content so id like to set a time limit like 30s to stop the `request`.

Something like

```
htmltext = requests.get(urls[0]).content
if(timer==30):
     print "request failed";
```

is this possible if so, how do i do this?

Comment: Use the 'timeout' property. Here are the docs for it: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts

Comment: @jeanggi90 thanks..